# Firefox weird behaviour right-align span inside li tag

Tags: css, firefox, html-lists, html

Firefox messes up the span tag inside li.
Chrome, Opera and IE do a good job of displaying the formatting correctly.

How can i fix it.

Here is my Code :

```
<div class="navcontainer">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One<span class="bubble-info">32</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Two<span class="bubble-warning">32</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Three<span class="bubble-danger">32</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Four<span class="bubble-success">32</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Five<span class="bubble-default">32</span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TgD65/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. When you set an element to be floating, you need to put it BEFORE the other element.

The browser first places the floating elements, then the rest.

So in your li if you have:

```
<a href="#"><span class="bubble-info">32</span>One</a>
```

it will work in all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/TgD65/5/

Answer (score 2):

Try using `white-space:normal` for `.nav ul ul a`

Answer (score 2):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgD65/4/)

Change the CSS of

`.bubble-info, .bubble-danger, .bubble-success, .bubble-default, .bubble-warning {`

To:

```
 .bubble-info, .bubble-danger, .bubble-success, .bubble-default, .bubble-warning {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

And add `position:relative;` to `.nav ul ul li li {`

What this does is replace the relative positioning of the bubbles with absolute positioning and give them block level characteristics so they can be given `right:0;` to be right aligned. It also removed the floating so you escape any related issues with not clearing it between items.

Answer (score 0):

@Madi,

you have to define `position:absolute;` in `Bubbles classes` Here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TgD65/1/).

```
.bubble-info, .bubble-danger, .bubble-success, .bubble-default, .bubble-warning {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:absolute; right:0; top:0; /*Added this line*/
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav ul a {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative; /*Added this line*/
    padding:10px;
}
```